# How to say ''Plug-and-Play" for a furniture item?

Tags: synonyms

I would like to express in English that my shelve doesn't require any assembly. Basically open the box, open the frame, put the racks and everything is ready to use.

I can't find any short term to express this idea, the closest I could found is plug-and-play but I am not sure it is suitable for furtniture.

PS: Because it is a promotional document, I am looking for a short word to express this idea.

Comment: No assembly required

Comment: @DhruvSaxena: That's something different. "modular" means that you can buy many different pieces of furniture which are all designed to fit together. It's close in meaning to "stackable", in the sense that you can buy any arbitrary amount of items (possibly even different types of item) and make them look like a singular whole. Lego blocks are modular, you can combine the pieces the way you want to. This doesn't have anything to do with a single piece of furniture requiring assembly or not.

Comment: Thanks @Flater. I see what you mean. I've removed the suggestion made in the previous comment for it being rather irrelevant now.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some options:

- *ready to use* furniture
- *pre-assembled* furniture
- *ready out of the box* furniture
- *ready*  furniture
- furniture *that requires no [further] assembly*
- *assembly-free* furniture

Comment: @HamzaBeno If this answers your questions, could you please kindly up vote and accept the answer? If not, please feel free to ask if you need further clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

***No tools required*** doesn't preclude minimal assembly and conveys the ease of setting up the furniture.
[**SmartDeco**](http://www.goodnet.org/articles/915) in the United States has adopted this idea. I'm sorry, I'm at a loss to come up with a one-word synonym for this phrase.

**EDIT:**

***Turnkey furniture*** could conceivably fit but a reader unfamiliar with the adjective (for example, as used in *turnkey systems* or *turnkey homes*) may draw a blank. Also, the shelves in question are not quite "complete and ready to use immediately" (see below).

[***turnkey***](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/turnkey)
Adjective
(especially of computer systems) complete and ready to use immediately

Comment: It's not exactly the same. [Cat scratching posts](https://s.s-bol.com/imgbase0/imagebase3/extralarge/FC/9/5/5/5/9200000059245559.jpg) (if that is the right name, I'm not sure) generally require assembly (putting the pieces together), but don't require any tools (you just screw the pieces together). Similarly, Lego's main purpose as a toy is assembling, but requires no tools.

Comment: _Minimal assembly_ is the crux, @Flater. The original poster wrote that his shelves don't require any assembly, however, the buyer has to _**open the frame and put in the racks.**_ That's a simple type of assembly. If my disabled neighbour were to order this item (sold as _**No assembly required**_) online, she would not expect to do the simple assembly and  probably would not be able to do so. Had the item been described as _**No tools required**_, she may not have ordered it. It's an exaggerated example, I know, but not implausible."Cat scratching posts" = Posts you scratch your cat with?

Comment: ([Cat]+[scratching post] though I mentioned I'm not sure about the English name for them) The OP has directly mentioned it _"doesn't require any assembly"_. Assembly without tools is still assembly. The scratching post I linked needs proper assembly (screwing pieces together), but the pieces have thread and you don't need a screwdriver as there are no loose screws. Also, there's a difference between putting something up and assembling it. You can argue that it's a grey area, but "no tools required" is not equivalent to "no assembly required", which is what the OP directly asked for.

Comment: I think I must concede the argument, @Flater. _No tools required_ just isn't going to sell these shelves! I'm pretty sure I couldn't have assembled your _cat scratching-post_ (it works for me) with or without tools. Besides, my dog would have deconstructed it in minutes. Thank you for your careful explanations.